# Cant get .htaccess to work proper

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am doing a URL-Shortener where i am trying to do it URL friendly.. Currently my adress is typed like this "example.com/index.php?name=sitename" i want it do be like "example.com/sitename".. I guess i could use some cool rewrite rule but i cant get it to work..

I did something like this but it wont work

```
Options All -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

but i dont know :s?

Comment: Whats the problem with this setup?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code you need to place in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

```
Options All +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression will fail on URLs with more than one `/` after the domain, because `[^/]` stops as soon as it sees one of these characters, and then it looks for the last slash with `/$`, which is not always the case.

Assuming you want to convert these URLs

```
example.com/HiThere
example.com/Your/Page
```

to:

```
example.com/index.php?name=HiThere
example.com/index.php?name=Your/Page
```

Try this rewrite rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

This will look for all characters with `(.*?)` UNTIL it reaches the last `/`. I'm not 100% sure about the `[L]` flag, though.

Comment: Right now my URLS looks like this 
`example.com/index.php?name=Avetile`
I want that to be:
`example.com/Avetile`

Comment: You should think the other way around. If a user visits `example.com/Avetile` that page actually doesn't exists. The server will look into the .htaccess and see this rule that converts that url to `example.com/index.php?name=Avetile`, which does exists. Then it loads that page under the first name.

Comment: he is using it in an URL-Shortener and there is no chances of repetance of '/'

Comment: This will cause infinite looping too.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest method is to use 404 error to point to index.php and then get the `sitename` using `php`
**.htaccess file**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php 
$sitename=substr(strrchr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"/"),"1");
```

now simply visit 'example.com/sitename' and sitename will be stored in `$sitename`.

And `if($sitename==""){//Show your HomePage}`

Hope it helps!!